# VS2017: git under build subfolder

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2017, versioning

I added my solution uncer VS2017 to "git" versioning control. I noticed that it created two files .gitattributes and .gitignore under /build subfolder. I also noticed that it marked  as locked only project names and not the files itself.

Any changes to my files (source and headers) are not captured and the git reports "there are no unstaged changes in the working directory". The solution file is layed under a subfolder of the main folder ie /project_name/build/vc2017.sln

So, the question is, what did I do wrong and how to fix/setup correctly this version control under Visual Studio 2017 ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the solution file right straight to main solution folder, but I had to re-adjust all include files inside each project of the solution, which it wasn't a trivial task.